# WCF Service , Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-client

i having this problem randomly and i able to add/delete/update using the WCFServiceClient and then i get the error and its happening randomly...

below is the client code that i am using...

```
using(WCFServiceClient client = new WCFServiceClient ()) 
{ 
     //More codes here 
     Employee emp = new Employee()
     emp = client.GetEmployeeDataById(123); //<<<ERROR    
}
```

I increase the timeout to two minutes but still the same:

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_IEmployeeService" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000" sendTimeout="00:02:00" >
```

//error:

*The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9990000. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.*

any help? i have seen many posts but none them seems any fix or any guidance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the actual service when you make the request? Also make sure that whatever increases in timeout you make on the server you make on the client as well.

Comment: i dont have any app.config on my server service, do i need to create?

Comment: The service that your client connects to defines the contract and binding parameters that your client interacts with. If your server sets the timeout to be x and your client sets it to why, the server setting will be that which is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

able to fix my problem after reading this link.

Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

The C# "using" statement results in a call to Dispose(). This is the same as Close(), which may throw exceptions when a network error occurs. Because the call to Dispose() happens implicitly at the closing brace of the "using" block, this source of exceptions is likely to go unnoticed both by people writing the code and reading the code. This represents a potential source of application errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try explicit binding selection to eliminate case where you might be picking up default (simplified config) binding

```
new WCFServiceClient ("WSHttpBinding_IEmployeeService")
```

Comment: i tried with explicit binding as you have suggested but still the same and i get the error after few minutes of browsing my app.

Comment: Can you explain bit more what you mean by "browsing my app"?

Comment: well what i mean is that i am consuming the services which provides bunch of methods like save, get, delete and etc.... in my client app i am using those services and everything is working fine as expected after few minutes of browing the app (which is consuming the services) then i get the error, which i posted in my orginal post. and i hope make it sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big the data is your getting there, but what about the receiveTimeout?

Comment: i was testing with less then 10 characters